# Why does my select box display things backwards in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following view code:
     <%= f.select :day_of_play, Team::DAYS_OF_WEEK %>

And I have to create the following map for it to work and display a select box:

```
DAYS_OF_WEEK = {"Sunday" => 0,
                  "Monday"=>  1,
                  "Tuesday"=> 2,
                  "Wednesday"=>3,
                  "Thursday"=>4,
                  "Friday"=>  5,
                  "Saturday"=>6,
  }
```

I store the integer in the database, but then when I display the integer it seems backwards that I have to create another map in order to go from integer->to->Saturday?

What am I doing wrong and how should I implement this correctly, soit is the dry principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to adhere to the DRY principle, I recommend using [`Date::DAYNAMES`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#DAYNAMES).

E.g. like this:

```
<%= f.select :day_of_play, Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index.collect { |day,i| [day,i] } %>
```